# Apache wont restart after I enable SSL

Tags: apache2, ssl

Once I a2enmod the ssl module and restart apache I get the following error:

```
Restarting web server apache2
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next 
release     /etc/apache2/ports.conf:14
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
[::]:443
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address
0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

To stop it I can either disenmod or comment out the following module lines in the ports.conf file:

```
Listen 80
#<IfModule ssl_module>
#    Listen 443
#</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please ask a question, not only summing up your problems, also a full configuration file could be useful or output of    netstat -l   to see what process is listening on 443. Maybe your answer is right in the ports.conf file you posted, there is mod_gnutls listening on port 443 also.

Answer (score 0):

Apache usually complains of "no listening sockets available, shutting down", when another process is listening on said socket.
Make sure that your apache instance is down or you don't have something else listening on said port. Use this command to find out who ( what pid) is bound to the port:

```
sudo netstat -anltp | grep 443
```

where a (all) l (listening) -t ( tcp ) -p (program/pid) -n (numeric ports)

Comment: tcp        0      0 MYIP:443        0.0.0.0:*           
    LISTEN      1553/openvpn-openss


That's what I get?

Comment: Ok from googling "no listening sockets available, shutting down"  I figured it out, I just do "kill 1553" and then when I reenter that command nothing comes up. I could restart apache fine.

Problem solved. thank you!

Comment: Looks like you have openvpn bound to 443. You have to choose what to run on that port. Either openvpn or apache. Make sure you correct openvpn conf in /etc because on the next restart apache will complain again!!!